# My react component is not formatting my text from my api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've been trying to get data from an api and display it in my React component.

I've finally gotten to a point where it's almost working!  I am getting the data from the API but it looks really messy.

It looks like this:

> {"data":{"id":3,"title":"Software Dev
> II","postDate":"2022-06-10T03:11:22.538","department":"Engineering",
> "jobType":"Mechanical &
> Maintenance","managerId":"409aa832","financialId":"91","contactPerson":"Mary
> Herarth"...

I have it in a div like this:

```
<div>
    {JSON.stringify(jobsData)}
</div>
```

and the code to get the api data looks like this:

```
 const getJobs = async (id) => {
    const data = await axios.get('api/openJobs/' + id);
    setJobsData(data);
}
```

I am getting no errors, just ugly formatting.

Is there a way to tell React to format it so it's readable?

Like:

```
Job Title: Software Dev II
Posting Date: 2021-06-10
Department: Engineering
```

etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you know what the format is, you can simply fill it in yourself:

```
jobsData = jobsData.data;
<div>
    <p>Job Title: {jobsData.title}</p>
    <p>Posting Date: {jobsData.postDate}</p>
    <p>Department: {jobsData.department}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but when I write out `jobsData = jobsData.data;` it just writes that out to the screen

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell of course, you need to put the statement (the assignment) out of your return statement, or of course it will render as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

HTML changes all extra spaces into a single space. You can wrap the text in `<pre>` (which doesn't have such behavior):

```
<div>
  <pre>{JSON.stringify(jobsData)}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: When I use `<pre>` it does change the look slightly but it still look unreadable for a website